# Why does Angular say "Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not using scope outside of the controller so I am confused why I keep getting the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined
```

It is from line 5 which is the "pollApp.controller" line.

(app.js)

```
var pollApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

pollApp.controller('choiceCtrl', [$scope, function ($scope) {
    $scope.choices = [{body: "test"}]; //just for testing

    $scope.addChoice = function () {

        //add new choice
        if ($scope.choiceBody) {
            $scope.choices.push({
                body: $scope.choiceBody
            });
            $scope.choiceBody = null;
        }
    }
}]);
```

I also checked that Angular is loading fine. Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Should be pollApp.controller('choiceCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

Comment: The quote arounds the `'$scope'`.

Comment: ya thanks i got it now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While asking for `dependency` using in `DI array annotation`, you need to wrap it a quotes like `'$scope'` inside array and then you could have instance of those dependency inside `factory` function on controller like `$scope`

```
pollApp.controller('choiceCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
```

Comment: @Gwen Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  pollApp.controller('choiceCtrl', ['$scope',
```

missing quotes

Comment: I had commas, I was just missing the single quotes